# Forward requests for subdomain to another DNS server in Windows 2k3

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

Let's say I control the example.com zone but not the abc.example.com. "abc.example.com" is controlled by another admin so I need to forward any requests for that subdomain to his BIND server.

example.com is running on Win2k3 while abc.example.com is running on BIND.

Comment: Just a note, this question is closely related to one I answered a while back: http://serverfault.com/questions/152444/add-a-subdomain-that-is-hosted-elsewhere

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an `NS` record in the `example.com` zone for the name `abc`, pointing to the BIND server.

Comment: I dont see that option under win2k3. I wonder if "delegation" is what I need.

Comment: Sorry; yes.  Delegation is the name they use for creating an `NS` record (which is how it'll show up once it's created).

Comment: How can I *forward* requests in this situation instead of delegating? Delegating makes the client send a request to the other NS - I want the server to do it and return the response.

Comment: After (only after) you create NS, you can create conditional forwarder. If there is no NS, you'll get an error (and this is correct)

Answer (score 3):

Your Win2K3 server is *authoritative* for the `example.com` zone, so when a request comes in for something in `abc.example.com`, it's going to see that it is an authority, look to its zone records, probably not find a match, and return NXDOMAIN to the client.

You need to first make your authoritative domain understand that it is *not authoritative* for the `abc.example.com` subdomain/zone.  To do that, in the `example.com` domain, add a **New Delegation** for `abc` (`.example.com` will be appended automatically).  You will be required to enter a FQDN for the `abc.example.com` name server(s) and one or more IP addresses if the FQDN doesn't automatically resolve.  The UI will complain if the DNS servers you point to are not *authoritative* for the zone, but you can proceed anyway (i.e. one or more are slaves).

The delegation will create the NS records for the `abc.example.com` zone in the parent `example.com` zone automatically, as well as any needed "glue" `A` (or `AAAA`) records to point to the child zone's DNS servers.  This is sufficient for *other* recursive DNS resolvers to find the `abc.example.com` DNS servers. However, workstation clients using your Win2K3 server as their resolver won't follow the glue records; they need your server to do the recursion for them.  But your server doesn't know to do the recursion yet.

Windows Sever 2003 introduced a feature called [Conditional Forwarding](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/step-by-step-standard-and-conditional-forwarding-in-windows-2003-dns/).  This allows you to specify the specific DNS servers that *your server* should use to handle requests for specific zones.  In your case, you would *also* add a conditional forwarder for `abc.example.com` and point it to the same IP(s) of that zone's name server(s).  Without this step, workstation clients will receive NXDOMAIN answers.  If you don't do the delegation step first, attempting to create a conditional forwarder may fail since the server is authoritative for the parent zone and would also be authoritative for the child zone without the delegation in place.

Comment: Thanks, you filled in the missing pieces for me! A year later but still useful, will let me setup things the way I wanted to before.