# Will Windows Server 2012 support a nested conditional forwarder?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, windows-dns

I work for a company with a split DNS configuration on the AD domain. I know that this is less than ideal, but I'm not in a position to drive change in this area. I own authoritative DNS (internal and external) where Active Directory is not involved, and another team owns the domain controllers.

Background:

- We have a split domain called `example.com` which lives on all the domain controllers.
- The DCs are configured to use forwarders for all domains that they are not authoritative for.
- There is a subdomain of that (`sub.example.com`) that is delegated to public IP addresses in a DMZ using `NS` records. I have a need to eliminate these IP addresses use internal IP addresses that are outside the DMZ.
- The new IP addresses are reachable from the forwarders, but not the domain controllers.

To represent this visually:

```
    example.com. (DCs are authoritative)
sub.example.com. (subdomain not managed by the DCs)
```

I would like to have the `sub.example.com. NS` records converted to a conditional forwarder that sends traffic along to the standard forwarders, but I am being told by our domain admins that Windows DNS will not allow a forwarder within a forward lookup zone.

Is it true that this is an unsupported configuration? Other DNS products have no problem with a forwarder that is beneath an authoritative zone, so I want to make sure I'm working with the correct information before I move on to a different strategy, such as firewall holes for every DC that bypass the forwarders. (argh)

I've already reviewed [Forward requests for subdomain to another DNS server in Windows 2k3](https://serverfault.com/questions/260142/forward-requests-for-subdomain-to-another-dns-server-in-windows-2k3) and the accepted answer that recommends a `NS` delegation, which doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll preface this with the disclaimer that I'm not very familiar with the MSDNS specifics.

First of all, I can confirm that if you try to just add such a forwarding zone (eg a `sub.example.com` forwarding zone when `example.com` exists as a regular zone) you are met with this error dialog:

```
---------------------------
DNS
---------------------------
A problem occurred while trying to add the conditional forwarder.
A zone configuration problem occurred.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

(Glorious ASCII representation auto-generated by Windows.)

However, as is noted in the [Using Forwarders](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754931.aspx) documentation (emphasis added):

> A DNS server cannot forward queries for the domain names in the zones
>   it hosts. For example, the authoritative DNS server for the zone
>   microsoft.com cannot forward queries according to the domain name
>   microsoft.com. **The DNS server authoritative for microsoft.com can
>   forward queries for DNS names that end with example.microsoft.com, if
>   example.microsoft.com is delegated to another DNS server.**

Ie, if you delegate `sub.example.com` elsewhere first (limiting the scope of your `example.com` zone) it then does allow you to add a forwarding zone for `sub.example.com`.

Whether going down this path actually works out for you will probably depend on the nitty gritty details of your scenario.

For what it's worth, I did notice is that it appears that MSDNS for some reason ignores the `RD` (recursion desired) bit for forwarding zones (ie, it forwards even when `RD` is not set), so it appears the above mentioned delegation is not actually visible in this setup.

Comment: Dead on. This is looking promising in our testing so far. I'm going to leave the question open for a few more days but it's looking like this is going to solve our problem. Thank you.

Comment: Just a follow up: we ended up deploying this workaround to our DCs nationwide and it's working great. Thanks again.